# PGFPlot, Legend line and legend text isnt on the same level

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north}]
        
\addplot {x};
        
\addlegendentry{$x$}
        
\addplot {x^2};
        
\addlegendentry{$x^2$}
    
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, as you can see in the picture, the legend text isnt at the same height as the legend line.

Do you know how to fix it?

Thank u very much!
Andre

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I get legend with text and symbols correct aligned.

Comment: i used:
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
    every axis legend/.style={
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},                  
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}}}

Comment: And what should this be good for? If you really should need it, replace `.style` by `.append style`. (By that you also get back the frame around the legend.)

Comment: `compat=1.11` Is somewhat “cutting lower edge”. You should probably use some newer version such as `1.18`.